# Android gridview animation (ordering) the list when removing or adding

Tags: android, animation, gridview

When I remove an item from a gridview, it fades out (because I start an animation) and all the other items change their place "at once".

Is there a simple way to animate all the other items to move, so the empty spot get filled up nicely animated, and not "at once"?

I would like to do the same for adding a new Item: all existing items will move animated and make a free place at the start of the grid where the new item will appear. I could of course do this by animating every item on itself, doing something different for the items at the end of a line, etc. But I would think there is already something prepared for this?

I checked out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/GridLayoutAnimationController.html

But that only seems to be useful for showing the grid come into view, not when it already is in view.

Also, if you know an open source program that implemented this, please let me know.

Comment: no, I'm fading all the grid items out and in again. Maybe I'll change it one day but it does not have priority.

Comment: I am also reached on same solution..but it cause a jerk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This helped me a lot, you can at least use the animations in this project, but maybe the whole thing will suit you:

https://github.com/mrKlar/PagedDragDropGrid

example on youtube here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYTSRfthSuQ

It looks like a gridview but isn't a gridview object. I used some of the code to change my own (android) gridview, but that was a great deal of work. If you can, just use this whole project.

Comment: The video is unavailable. Do you have any alternate tutorial for this?